# undefined is not an object error when adding BIP39 to React Native

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, bip44

I have a React Native Project and it was worked correctly till I added `bip39` package to the project. when i try to require `bip39` in my component i get the below error.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'superCtor.prototype')

inherits
inherits_browser.js:5:45
<unknown>
index.js:23:9
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
index.js:3:22
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
browser.js:3:17
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
index.js:2:24
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
BIP39.js:1:19
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
Mnemonic.js:5
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
App.js:5
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
<unknown>
index.js:7
loadModuleImplementation
require.js:320:6
guardedLoadModule
require.js:207:45
global code
<unknown file>:0
```

React Native Version `0.57.7`

React Version `16.6.1`

bip39 version `2.5.0`

Comment: Can you provide more information, like when is this error thrown?

Comment: @JBaczuk when i add `const bip = require('bip39')` in component